# React and Google Autocomplete with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-api, react-bootstrap

I have a google address autcomplete and a react-bootstrap form and I can't make the types match for the `ref`.

```
class ProfileForm extends React.Component<PropsFromRedux, ProfileFormState> {
    private myRef = React.createRef<FormControl<any>>();
    private autocomplete?: google.maps.places.Autocomplete;
    ...

}
```

My Form control is like this:

```
<Form.Control ref={this.myRef} type="text" placeholder="Enter address"
              defaultValue={this.props.userProfile.location!.formatted_address}
/>
```

Here is how I create my autocomplete:

```
function forceCast<T>(input: any): T {
    // @ts-ignore <-- forces TS compiler to compile this as-is
    return input;
}


//@ts-ignore
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        forceCast<HTMLInputElement>(this.myRef.current),
        options);
```

My question is:

How do I do this without the force cast?

The google autocomplete wants an `HTMLInputElement` (I've tried loads of other types and stuff) but the best I can get with react-bootstrap is the `FormControl` (I can't figure out how to "cast" this to anything any other way than what is shown).